# Lookup GAL from Outlook

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a tool which is required to look up the GAL in Outlook to find a certain employee and return their email address, their manager & manager's email address & finally their manager & manager's email address.

I found code and adjusted it to search for a person's name; however, if you have two Bob Smiths I require this to be more specific in its search, either by email address or by alias.

Any code I found creates an array with all users in the exchange server; however, with millions of employee records this takes a large amount of time and this would run once per week to update the information.

Is there a way to search ideally by alias or secondly by SMTP email address?

I found versions of the code and I modified them to suit my requirements but still unable to find by alias or email address. If I do this manually I can click on advance search and type the alias or I click on "more columns" and search the alias and the correct result appears.

Can I define "More Columns" in the VBA code?

```
    Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Namespace
    Dim myAddrList As AddressList
    Dim myAddrEntry As AddressEntry
    Dim AliasName As String
    Dim i As Integer, r As Integer
    Dim c As Range
    Dim EndRow As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim exchUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser

    Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNameSpace = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myAddrList = myNameSpace.AddressLists("Global Address List")
    Dim FullName As String, LastName As String, FirstName As String
    Dim LDAP As String, PhoneNum As String
    Dim StartRow As Integer

    EndRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    StartRow = 2

    For Each c In Range("I" & StartRow & ":I" & CStr(EndRow))
        AliasName = LCase(Trim(c))
        c = AliasName
        Set myAddrEntry = myAddrList.AddressEntries(AliasName)
        Set exchUser = myAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser

        If Not exchUser Is Nothing Then
            c.Offset(0, 1) = exchUser.FirstName
            c.Offset(0, 2) = exchUser.LastName
            c.Offset(0, 3) = exchUser.Alias
            c.Offset(0, 4) = exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
            c.Offset(0, 5) = exchUser.Manager
           'etc...
        End If
    Next c
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the `CreateRecipient` namespace? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient

You could try creating a `recipient` object passing the alias to the `CreateRecipient` method:

```
Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set recip = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("YourAlias")
recip.Resolve
```

You should of course check if your recipient was properly resolved by checking the `resolved` property:

`If recip.Resolved Then
'Do something`

After you got your recipient you can create an Exchange User from it using the `GetExchangeUser` method from the `AdressEntry` property in your recipient object.

```
Set exchUser = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
Debug.Print exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
```

And I'm sure you can work it out from there!

Comment: Thanks, I have gone down this route and now have 5 functions to return the values however I was wondering is there a simple way to return the multiple values possibly as objects? I am able to return single strings and build the content required but as it is repeatedly checking the Exchange server it is low. 

Also one additional error with this method if you know a way around this is I have a Alias as 12345 & 123456 Whenever I try 12345 it fails to resolve? Any way to force this to pick the correct user? I will add a post with the new code...

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way. You're running GetName every time you need the property of an object which calls CreateRecipient and Resolve on every item you want to retrieve.

Instead, try to create a function that returns a recipient object and then retrieve the desired properties from that object. Doing it that way you won't need to call resolve every single time which I'm sure unnecessarily hammers the Exchange  server.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find a work around solution with the following function.

```
Function GetName(strAcc As String) As Variant

Dim lappOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim lappNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim lappRecipient As Outlook.Recipient

'Dim strAcc As String

Dim maxTries As Long
Dim errCount As Long

Set lappOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set lappNamespace = lappOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")


Set lappRecipient = lappNamespace.CreateRecipient(strAcc)

maxTries = 2000

On Error GoTo errorResume

Retry:

    DoEvents

    ' For testing error logic. No error with my Excel 2013 Outlook 2013 setup.
    ' Should normally be commented out
    'Err.Raise 287

    lappRecipient.Resolve

On Error GoTo 0


Set olAddrEntry = lappRecipient.AddressEntry



If lappRecipient.Resolved Then
    Set olexchuser = olAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser

    GetName = olexchuser.Name
Else
    GetName = "Unable To Validate LDAP"
End If

ExitRoutine:

    Set lappOutlook = Nothing
    Set lappNamespace = Nothing
    Set lappRecipient = Nothing

    Exit Function

errorResume:

    errCount = errCount + 1

    ' Try until Outlook responds
    If errCount > maxTries Then

        ' Check if Outlook is there and Resolve is the issue
        lappNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Display
        GoTo ExitRoutine

    End If

    'Debug.Print errCount & " - " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume Retry

End Function
```

Is there a way to return the following Exchange Values to consolidate the function so it only looks in the exchange server once ?

Obtain .Name
.PrimarySmtpAddress
.Manager
.Manager.PrimarySmtpAddress
.Manager.Alias

I then loop through and Get Managers, Manager & Email.

I use the following SUB to be able to pull the information needed (Into a message box while building but the data will populate a table once finished).

```
Sub GetDetails()
Dim Name As String, Email As String, Manager As String, ManagersEmail As String, MD As String, MDEmail As String, Lookup As String

Lookup = GetManagerAlias("3511931")    '("3359820")

Name = GetName(Lookup)
Email = GetEmail(Lookup)
Manager = GetManager(Lookup)
ManagersEmail = GetManagersEmail(Lookup)
MD = GetManager(GetManagerAlias(Lookup))
MDEmail = GetManagersEmail(GetManagerAlias(Lookup))

MsgBox Name & vbNewLine & Email & vbNewLine & Manager & vbNewLine & ManagersEmail & vbNewLine & MD & vbNewLine & MDEmail

End Sub
```